# Don't want to wait for method to return

Tags: c#, qtp

Is there a way to "tell" C# not to wait for object's method to return?

Using COM (VbScript) I'm able to fire a method without waiting for it to return, so I would like to use C# the same way.

The VbScript Code:

```
Dim qtApp
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtApp.Open("C:\Temp\Test")

qtApp.Run   '// VbScript does not wait for this method to finish

Set qtApp = Nothing
```

The C# code:

```
//Refer the object
var qtApp = new QuickTest.Application();
//Open the test
qtApp.Open("C:\\Temp\\Test");

qtApp.Test.Run(); //<<== @ this step my code is waiting for the Run method to return
qtApp.Test.Pause(); //<<== This line is never executed until Run returns
```

Comments:

1. The object referred (`QuickTestApplication`) is COM object has methods for Run and Pause ( as mentioned in the code above).
2. For me `QuickTestApplication` is a black box
3. I do not want to use `Thread` or `ASync` (which is basically threading), but the `QuickTestApplication`build in methods

I really look for simple answer if it can be done using C#

Comment: Run the method on a separate thread? Can you please give more details?

Comment: Is the COM object in question affinitized to the current thread? Remember, COM objects are often single threaded apartment model.

Comment: @EricLippert: My application is not single-threaded, and I would like to use its methods. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Tudor: using threading is not an option (design issues). Thank  you for your reply

Comment: @EricLippert QTP automation object is an STA object. The answer to this question is application specific your expertise in C# will not be sufficient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QTP automation allows running a test asynchronously, look at the documentation:

[image: Documentation for Run method]

So instead of running plain `Run` (on the `Test` Property not the QTP application as you did in your sample) you have to provide a default result-options and then specify `False` for `WaitOnReturn`

```
Set resOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions")
qtApp.Test.Run resOpt, False
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check it out first thing on Sunday and inform this post.

Answer (score 3):

Execute it asynchronously.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301332.aspx

> The .NET Framework enables you to call any method asynchronously. To
> do this you define a delegate with the same signature as the method
> you want to call; the common language runtime automatically defines
> BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods for this delegate, with the
> appropriate signatures.
>
> The BeginInvoke method initiates the asynchronous call. The EndInvoke method retrieves the results of the asynchronous call.

Comment: Async is not what I'm looking for, as I titled - I don't want to wait for to return. async is a bypass for that.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use a "Task", and run the method in that.  I haven't used these yet, but I believe that is the purpose of them in C#.

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

"A task represents an asynchronous operation, and in some ways it resembles the creation of a new thread or ThreadPool work item, but at a higher level of abstraction. Tasks provide two primary benefits:

More efficient and more scalable use of system resources.

Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been enhanced with algorithms (like hill-climbing) that determine and adjust to the number of threads that maximizes throughput. This makes tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to enable fine-grained parallelism. To complement this, widely-known work-stealing algorithms are employed to provide load-balancing.

More programmatic control than is possible with a thread or work item.

Tasks and the framework built around them provide a rich set of APIs that support waiting, cancellation, continuations, robust exception handling, detailed status, custom scheduling, and more.

For both of these reasons, in the .NET Framework 4, tasks are the preferred API for writing multi-threaded, asynchronous, and parallel code."

```
// Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression.
var taskA = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));

// Start the task.
taskA.Start();

// Output a message from the joining thread.
Console.WriteLine("Hello from the calling thread.");


/* Output:
* Hello from the joining thread.
* Hello from taskA. 
*/
```

Comment: Using Task is basically relying on threading, while I want to use the object's interface.